# Why can't I just do view.destroy()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement some basic MVC into a program of mine, and I want the controller to give the buttons functionality. Here is my current code:

```
import tkinter

class View(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.title("Red Frame Example")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        container_frame = tkinter.Frame(self)
        container_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True) 
        container_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self._red_frame = RedFrame(container_frame)
        self._red_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
    @property
    def red_frame(self):
        return self._red_frame
              
class RedFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="red")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self._quit_button = tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', width=25)
        self._quit_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
    @property
    def quit_button(self):
        return self._quit_button    
        
class Controller:
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view
        self.view.red_frame.quit_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.quit)
        
    def quit(self, event):
        self.view.destroy()
             
class App:
    view = View()
    controller = Controller(view)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.view.mainloop()
```

This works just fine, but I'm wondering why, in the `Controller` class, I can't do `view.red_frame.etc...` or `view.destroy()`, I have to do `self.view`. In the code below, I don't need to use `self.view` anywhere, yet it still works just as intended. Why is that? What is `self.view = view` doing if I can't use `view` in place of `self.view` later on in the class?

```
import tkinter

class View(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.title("Red Frame Example")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        container_frame = tkinter.Frame(self)
        container_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True) 
        container_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self._red_frame = RedFrame(container_frame)
        self._red_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
    @property
    def red_frame(self):
        return self._red_frame
              
class RedFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="red")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self._quit_button = tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', width=25)
        self._quit_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
    @property
    def quit_button(self):
        return self._quit_button    
        
class Controller:
    def __init__(self, view):
        view.red_frame.quit_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.quit)
        
    def quit(self, event):
        view.destroy()
             
if __name__ == "__main__":
    view = View()
    controller = Controller(view)
```

Comment: You're asking a very basic Python question.  In the first case, view is an instance variable of a class, and within the class's functions it is accessed as self.view.  In the second case, view is a global variable and as such does not need to be accessed with the dot notation.  You should do a basic Python tutorial, such as the one that comes with the python.org download.  You will have a hard time understanding, let alone writing, any useful Python program if you don't understand this.